# Will the database send over ALL the records if I don't use Take(1) before FirstOrDefault() in LINQ + Entity Framework?

Tags: database, entity-framework, linq

Let's assume I'm using Entity Framework with a "Users" table, and 500,000 of these users have either blue eyes or brown eyes. Let's also assume that I'm connected to the database over the internet. I want to get **the first User that satisfies this condition** in LINQ, but **I don't want the engine to send ALL the satisfying records over the internet**.

```
public static User GetUser()
{
    return DB.Users.Where(x => x.EyeColor == "blue" || x.EyeColor == "brown").Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If I don't I apply **Take(1)** to the LINQ query, will the database send all 500,000 satisfying records over the internet? Or is the LINQ engine smart enough without **Take(1)** to tell the database only to send over one record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the documentation, then if in doubt with regards to what queries EF will actually use, run a Profiler against the database and you will see exactly what queries EF is running, which you can re-run against the database to review exactly what data is coming back.

With regards to `First`/`FirstOrDefault` yes, these will pull back one row without `Take`. What you do want to add though is an OrderBy clause to ensure the call is predictable. For instance, if there are 2 or more users with blue or brown eyes, which should be picked? Order By ID or a CreatedAt timestamp, or by age, etc.

You can specify filtering in a `Where` clause or as part of the `FirstOrDefault`

```
return DB.Users
    .Where(x => x.EyeColor == "blue" || x.EyeColor == "brown")
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedAt)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

is the same as:

```
return DB.Users
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedAt)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EyeColor == "blue" || x.EyeColor == "brown");
```

Using `Where` is generally preferable as it lets you easily combine filter criteria conditionally.

`Take` is generally used with `Skip` to provide pagination where you want to retrieve sub-sets of data, like pages of 100 results at a time.

Note also that `*AsDefault()` methods will return #null if no data is found. Only use these if no matching data is a valid state. Anything using the results of a `*AsDefault()` method should be checking for Null.